# how to link the date and time

Tags: c#, sql

I need to show this time in the program every day, since I made a calendar table (all dates), I can make another table only with this time, and get a preview like this:

```
13.11.2018 - 00:00-01:00
13.11.2018 - 01:00-02:00
13.11.2018 - 03:00-03:30
13.11.2018 - 03:30-07:00
13.11.2018 - 07:00-09:00
13.11.2018 - 09:00-14:00 ...
```

Can I make a timeline with this time and link it somehow to any date, or what can I do to get this result and display it in DataviewGrid?

thanks for your help

Comment: could u plz show us how your final output will be look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be best to define your times as integer numbers of minutes in one table, and then use the `DateTime.AddMinutes(int)` C# function to add them to the dates.

Comment: Bennet I think you're right, trying to make a suggestion. thank you